# Edit Image not available in local Wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress

I developed an wordpress plugin which uses the media upload function of wordpress to upload images. 
Know the customer wants an extension for this plugin this is why I start developing again.
I had to set up an new wordpress on my localhost because i got a new pc.

When everyhing was established i noticed that the edit image button is not available anymore.

[image: No Edit Image]

I looked on the server of the customer but there everything was fine.

[image: With Edit Image]

I already tried to set up a new wordpress installation without plugins or any themes but this didn´t help.
I´m using Wordpress version 3.6.1

What can cause my problem that the image edit function is not availiable on my local machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need code snippets or we can't help you! :(

Comment: Check for any static paths (file/url) in your code? Use any caching? Where's your code?

Comment: It´s nothing about my code code I set up a new apache, mysql and wordpress without any line of code from me but the edit image button is not there.

If i view the code of the html site i can see the div container.


<div style="display:none" class="image-editor" id="image-editor-4"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GD is not installed on your local machine http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: Omg i can´t remember i activated this earlier.
Activating the php_gd2.dll extension in the php.ini solved my problem.